# OCaml syntax for defining a helper function inside of another function?

Tags: function, syntax, scope, ocaml, helper

I apologize if this is a silly question, but I'm a newbie to OCaml and I wasn't able to find examples of this anywhere. Could somebody give me a simple example of the Ocaml syntax for defining a helper function inside of another function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
let outer x y =
  let inner z = x + z
  in inner y
```

Comment: The Right Way to thank is to accept the answer (by clicking on the check).